# Unique real number proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I am working on a question from Velleman's How To Prove It, it is as follows: Prove that there is a unique real number x such that for every real number y, xy+x-4=4y.

Which seems to me corresponds to the following logical form: $\exists x \forall y(xy+x-4=4y \land\forall z(yz+y-4=4z\to x=z))  $ (Edit: I corrected the conditional, an earlier version had x instead of y)

I have two confusions:

1. Is my logical form correct? It seems that intuitively the $\exists x$ and $\forall y$ are not in the right positions, but according to how the question is phrased this looks right.
2. Perhaps the more important question: I solved $xy+x-4=4y$ and find $x=(4y+4)/(y+1)$. This means that x is undefined if $y=-1$, because the denominator will be zero. If my understanding is right -1 is also a real number: but the question states that this applies to 'every real number y', so how is this possible?

Thank you so much!

---

Edit: Here is my proof: I solved $xy+x-4=4y$ and find $x=(4y+4)/(y+1)$. Then letting z to be an arbitrary item, assuming the antecedent, I find $z=(4y+4)/(y+1)$. Since both x and z equal to (4y+4)/(y+1), they are identical.

Comment: the given equation represents the rectangular hyperbola:(x-4)(y-1)=0 .

Comment: can you complete the proof?

Comment: Notice that if $y=-1$, then $\frac{4y+4}{y+1}=\frac{0}{0}$. How should $\frac{0}{0}$ be interpreted in this case?

Comment: @JustinBenfield 0/0...? Google tells me it is either undetermined or undefined. Which case should apply here?

Comment: @DanielMak
Yes the quantifier order is correct (and in fact, important). Having the $\exists$ before the $\forall$ means that there is _one_ $x$ that will work for _all_ $y$'s. The other way around would only say that you can _find_ an $x$ for each $y$, meaning that the choice of $x$ would depend on the $y$.

Comment: @DanielMak As for $\frac{0}{0}$, it is an indeterminant form in this case, however, we can simplify the expression to see what it should be interpreted as: Note that the numerator has a common factor of $4$, which can be factored out, do you see how the expression simplifies now?

Comment: @JustinBenfield It looks like it will simplify to 4(y+1)/(y+1), and if we let y=-1 it comes to 4(-1+1)/(-1+1)? But I am not sure how this simplification helps to interpret this answer?

Comment: @DanielMak I meant algebraically; that is $\frac{4y+4}{y+1}=\frac{4(y+1)}{y+1}=4$.

Comment: @JustinBenfield Thank you for your answer and patience to explain!